# How to serve file from gridfs in django development environment?

Tags: django, mongoengine, gridfs

I need to serve file from GridFS in my django + mongoengine project. Is there any out of the box solution?

Answer (score 0):

@login_required
def view_posts(request):
    post_data = Post.objects(user=request.user)

```
return render(request, 'posts.html', { 'post_data' : post_data } )
```

@login_required
def show_image(request, _md5):
    post_data = Post.objects(user=request.user)

```
image = None
for post in post_data:
    if _md5 == post.image.md5:
        image = post.image.read()
        break

return HttpResponse(image.read(), content_type="image/" + post.image.format)
```

Answer (score -1):

It wasn't immediately obvious how I should do this in Django but here's what I ended up doing.

I create a show_image function in views.py that is passed the md5 of the image of interest and returns it as an HttpResponse. In this case the post data is filtered by user but in general you probably don't need to. Also my show_image code is pretty inefficient, i'm fairly certain there is way to do a query using mongoengine which would be more efficient than iterating through the images looking for the md5. The urls.py passes the md5 of the image which then calles show_image and returns an HttpResponse/url need for the  tag.

**models.py**

```
from mongoengine import *

class Post(Document):
    image = ImageField()
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def view_posts(request):
    post_data = Post.objects(user=request.user)

    return render(request, 'posts.html', { 'post_data' : post_data } )

@login_required
def show_image(request, _md5):
    post_data = Post.objects(user=request.user)

    image = None
    for post in post_data:
        if _md5 == post.image.md5:
            image = post.image.read()
            break

    return HttpResponse(image, content_type="image/" + post.image.format)
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'posts/images/(?P<_md5>\w+)$', 'project.views.show_image', name='show_image'),
```

**templates/posts.html**

```
<div id="posts">
    {% for post in post_data %}
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dd>{{ post.image.uploadDate }}</dd>
        <img src="images/{{ post.image.md5 }}" />
    </dl>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Note: this could be modified to use the Object Id instead of the md5 which might make this more generic.